# How do I go about upgrading Netty on JBoss AS 6.1?

Tags: jboss, netty, jboss6.x

How do I go about upgrading Netty on JBoss AS 6.1 ?

Do you just replace the netty jar ?

Answer (score 0):

We really try hard to keep backward compabilty. So yes just replace the jar should work